# SwiftUI: How to make a CoreData entity conform to a protocol?

Tags: core-data, swiftui, nsmanagedobject

I'm new to CoreData but managed to integrated it into my project. Now I need that one of my entities conform to a protocol I created. How can I achieve this? I tried but I can't get it right.

My protocol:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    init(text: String)
}
```

`CoreData` entity A:

```
@objc(A)
public class A: NSManagedObject, MyProtocol {
    
    required init(text: String) {
        super.init()                 // Error!
        self.name = text
    }
    
}

extension A {
    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<A> {
        return NSFetchRequest<A>(entityName: "A")
    }

    @NSManaged public var id: UUID
    @NSManaged public var name: String
}

extension A : Identifiable, CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { name }
}
```

UPDATE:
I need conformance to `MyProtocol` because I have a reusable view that takes an array of "objects" which may add/remove items to the array (this changes may not need to be persisted by CoreData, these may be just temporary objects). Therefore, I need to make sure that for any object I pass to this view there's a way to create the corresponding instance with this minimum requirement (a text property). See example below:

```
struct ReusableView<Element: My Protocol>: View {
    var data: [Element]

    var body: some View {
        //some code

        Button(action: {
            let newElement = Element(text: "test")
            data.append(newElement)
        }, label: {
            Text("Add new Element")
        })

        //more code

        Text("some element name: \(data[0].description)")
    }
}

//... other file

struct MainView: View {
    var entitiesA: [A] //CoreData entity A
    var entitiesB: [B] //CoreData entity B

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            //some code
            ReusableView(entitiesA)
        
            //some code
            ReusableView(entitiesB)
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I need to implement protocol `CustomStringConvertible` so that I'm able to access to a "`description`" property.

All that for a CoreData object. Is this even possible? Am I doing it right?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you explain why you need a protocol with just an init, what do you want to achieve? And why it can't take a NSManagedObjectContext as a parameter?

Comment: Hi @JoakimDanielson, I've updated the description of my problem.

Comment: This is not a good solution, using core data objects as temporary objects means you will have to write code that delete the temporary objects when the view closes or they will be saved to the store the next time you call `save()` on the NSManagedObjectContext they belong to. If you don't do that they will show up the next time you open the view and/or start the app. I think such a solution will be very hard to manage.

Answer (score 0):

Call designated initializer

```
public init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertInto context: NSManagedObjectContext?)
```

Like this:

```
let context: NSManagedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType(rawValue: 0)!) // Your context

@objc(A)
public class A: NSManagedObject, MyProtocol {
    
    required init(text: String) {
        super.init(entity: NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "A", in: context)!, insertInto: context)
        self.name = text
    }
    
}
```

Note: Cotext is an example. Use your context

Comment: Hi @RajaKishan, I've updated the description of my post with more details about the problem I'm facing.